# iOS 7 Remove padding in NSString draw

Tags: ios, objective-c, uifont

When I'm drawing text in taped location, I get an extra padding on the ordinate.

Getting touch coordinate

```
(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];
    self.currentPoint = location;
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];
    self.currentPoint = location;
   [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

 - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
 {
     NSString *text = @"a";
     UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:150];
     NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle]  
      mutableCopy];
     paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
     NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName:font,
                             NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle};

    [text drawAtPoint:self.currentPoint withAttributes:attributes];

}
```

[image]

How can I remove this extra padding?